# CMake substitute text in a file generated by a target

Tags: windows, cmake

I have cmake target which runs a setup.exe on windows which installs a tool using add_custom_target as follows

```
# TOOL_TEMP_INSTALL_PATH is the installation path which is set earlier in cmake
add_custom_target(
    install_tool
    COMMAND ${TOOL_TEMP_DIR}/setup.exe /DIR=${TOOL_TEMP_INSTALL_PATH}
)
```

After the installation, I want to replace text in a configuration file located at ${TOOL_TEMP_INSTALL_PATH}/tool.ini replacing a line of text "LICENSE_FILE=Enter License server" with  "LICENSE_FILE=30309@server"

Following commands will achieve this but this needs to be run after install_tool target is built.

```
file(READ "${TOOL_TEMP_INSTALL_PATH}/tool.ini" filedata)
string(REGEX REPLACE "LICENSE_FILE=Enter License server here" 
"LICENSE_FILE=30309@server" filedata "${filedata}")
file(WRITE  "${TOOL_TEMP_INSTALL_PATH}/tool.ini" "${filedata}")
```

How can I add these commands as a dependency to install_tool? Or is there a better way to achieve this on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to run two things in order as part of the same target, you can use multiple COMMAND entries in the same target.  The difficulty is that COMMAND can't handle CMake code, but only system commands.  The typical solution is to call CMake in a subshell on a script file:

`COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P path_to_script`

So, place your file modification commands in a file in your source tree called `license-install.cmake`, and add another COMMAND to your `add_custom_target`

Hint: You might consider `add_custom_command` instead, so you can specify a file in the installed tree as a dependency.  This will allow CMake to see the installed tool as a build product, and to skip the install step if the tool is already installed.  You'll still need an `add_custom_target` with a dependency on your command output to hook it in correctly.